# Aligning Chemical Reaction

Tags: chemfig

In latex i have written 3 different type of reaction and the problem is the middle arrow align according to reactants .

```
Eg. 
A + B -> C
A + B + C -> D

I want to align like this 
A + B     -> C
A + B + C -> D
```

I want to align these particular reactions

```
 \begin{document}

\title{Aromatic Hydrocarbons}

\section{General Method of Preparation of Benzene}


    \subsection{Decarboxylation (From Sodium Benzoate)}

    \schemestart
      \sodiumbenzoaten \+ \NaOH \arrow(.{4.85}--){->[\footnotesize\chemfig{CaO}][$\Delta$]} \benzenen   \+ \CaO
    \schemestop


    \subsection{From Phenol}

    \schemestart
      \phenoln \+ \chemfig{Zn} \arrow(.{4.85}--){->[$\Delta$]} \benzenen   \+ \ZnO
    \schemestop


    \subsection{From Reduction of Cholorobenzene}

    \schemestart
      \chlorobenzenen   \arrow(.{4.85}--){->[\chemfig{LiAlH_4}]} \benzenen   \+ \chemfig{HCl}
    \schemestop




\end{document}
```

is it possible? I find it don't work like math array while aligning equations :(

and I also want to align name like sodium benzoate  towards left (i don't know why they appears to be right )

```
\def\sodiumbenzoaten{\chemname{COONa-[4]**6(------)}{Sodium Benzoate_ZZZZ}}
```

The text Sodium Benzoate_ZZZZ below the structure  appears abit right how do i bring it abit left  ?

So, How to align these reactions ? How to align the name of sodium benzoate abit left ? How to make arrow length longer ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to the site.  But please, provide code that compiles, starting with `\documentclass`.  Save time and effort for the people trying to help you by making your example compact but complete.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Ok i provided starting with document class :)

Comment: @aftershock You documentclass is still missing. I do not know, how to compile your code. Please complete this

Comment: Could you add the definition of `\benzene` as well? And while you're at it, add a `\documentclass`, the necessary `\usepackage`s, and whatever else is needed to compile your example.